# GPUImage record OpenGL ES scene's texture, video is black

Tags: opengl-es, textures, gpuimage

i am using GPUImageTextureInput and GPUImageMovieWriter,

but i always got a black video.

do  i miss something?   i have spent days on this.

the frameBuffer and texture setup is here:

```
self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 sharegroup:[[[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] context] sharegroup]];



[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    GLenum status;

glGenFramebuffers(1, &newFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, newFrameBuffer);




glGenTextures(1, &outputTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,  640, 1136 , 0, GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture, 0);
```

and the movie writer:

```
    textureInput = [[GPUImageTextureInput alloc] initWithTexture:outputTexture size:size];

NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f.mp4", NSTemporaryDirectory(),
                           [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]]];



movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(640, 1136)];
movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = YES;


[textureInput addTarget:movieWriter];

double delayToStartRecording = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t sstartTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayToStartRecording * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(sstartTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"Start recording");

    //videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
    [movieWriter startRecording];

    started = YES;

    //        NSError *error = nil;
    //        if (![videoCamera.inputCamera lockForConfiguration:&error])
    //        {
    //            NSLog(@"Error locking for configuration: %@", error);
    //        }
    //        [videoCamera.inputCamera setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
    //        [videoCamera.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];

    double delayInSeconds = 20.0;
    dispatch_time_t stopTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(stopTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){




        [movieWriter finishRecordingWithCompletionHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"Movie completed");
            finished = YES;

        }];

        //            [videoCamera.inputCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];
        //            [videoCamera.inputCamera setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        //            [videoCamera.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];
    });
});
```

and the drawInRect

```
[(GLKView*)self.view bindDrawable];

glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

// Render the object with GLKit
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

// Render the object again with ES2
glUseProgram(_program);

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

glFlush();


//[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, newFrameBuffer);
glViewport(0,0, 640,1138);

glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

// Render the object with GLKit
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

// Render the object again with ES2
glUseProgram(_program);

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

glFlush();

// some GPUImage code
```

Comment: Not sure why it is black. I notice you are missing a **glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);** at the end of **drawInRect** which is good practice due to multiple FBOs. Slightly offtopic - it looks like your drawInRect is drawing the geometry twice.  Since you have a secondary FBO you can render to that first then just render whole thing as a simple quad render texture in one go to the main FBO. http://mickyd.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/creating-render-to-texture-secondary-framebuffer-objects-on-ios-using-opengl-es-2/

Comment: What happens if you just render the geometry and turn of the video recording for now?

Comment: the render geometry is ok, i can see it on screen, but the recording video is black.

Comment: Can you create an openGL frame snapshot and confirm your output texture is not black? Also are those sizes all ok and check the frame buffer status after the texture attachment?

Answer (score 0):

My framebuffer output / output texture was black as well. I tried a lot of stuff, a few days on and off debugging, mostly following the CubeExample from Brad Larson.

As soon as I added this call, things started showing up:

`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)`

AFTER calls to `glTexImage2D` and `glFramebufferTexture2D`

Here's that example project for reference. https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/iOS/CubeExample